# keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, –delete is not a legal command

Tags: java, keytool

I am trying to set up an SSL on an ahsayobs with no luck.  The first step is to delete the default certificate that comes installed on the machine.  I'm running java version 1.6.  Here is what I'm doing:

```
[root@backup ~]# /data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool –delete –alias tomcat –keystore /Applications/AhsayOBS/conf/keystore
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, –delete is not a legal command
[root@backup ~]# /data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x64/bin/keytool –delete –alias tomcat –keystore /Applications/AhsayOBS/conf/keystore
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, –delete is not a legal command
[root@backup ~]# /data/obs/java-linux-x64/bin/keytool –delete –alias tomcat –keystore /Applications/AhsayOBS/conf/keystore
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, –delete is not a legal command
```

The next step is to create a CSR which also comes back with the `Usage error, –genkey is not a legal command`.  It's like the `keytool` isn't even installed.  But I don't get that error, and `locate keytool` shows a few different locations for it (which I've tried them all).  Each one shows the same error.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Oh geesh...  It seems that the article I had copied/pasted the command from (keytool -delete -alias... etc) had not used a regular hyphen, and that was what was throwing it off.  Here is what I used in the end:

```
### First, delete the previous keystore file
/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -delete -alias tomcat -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore

### Then, create a new keystore file
/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore

### You will be asked for normal SSL info such as your name, department, company, etc.

/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore

### Save the intermediate certificate and the SSL certificate into the /data/obs/conf/ folder
### Use the below commands to import them into the keytool
/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -import -alias intermed -trustcacerts -file sf_intermediate.crt -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore
/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -import -alias tomcat -trustcacerts -file backup.atomicx.com.crt -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore

### Check the keytool to make sure it was successful
/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -list -alias tomcat -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore

### Make sure /data/obs/conf/server.xml has the correct keystore folder path
<-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 --> <!-- <Connector port="8443" maxThreads="200"
scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="path to your keystore file" keystorePass="changeit" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Comment: Though I am not an expert in Linux, but did you ensure that you have the permission to run keytool? Another try would be to run keytool right from the directory it is in.

Comment: @SergioPelin Thanks Sergio, but I actually am running it from the directory it is in, in every directory it is in with no luck (see above).  I did not check the permissions, though.  But yes, I am logging in as root and root has execute permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out where I had copied and pasted the commands, the hyphens were not actually hyphens, but em dashes.  Once I replaced those, I was no longer getting the error.  However, here is everything that I did do at that point in case anyone needs it.

```
### First, delete the previous keystore file
/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -delete -alias tomcat -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore

### Then, create a new keystore file
/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore

### You will be asked for normal SSL info such as your name, department, company, etc.

/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore

### Save the intermediate certificate and the SSL certificate into the /data/obs/conf/ folder
### Use the below commands to import them into the keytool
/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -import -alias intermed -trustcacerts -file sf_intermediate.crt -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore
/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -import -alias tomcat -trustcacerts -file backup.atomicx.com.crt -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore

### Check the keytool to make sure it was successful
/data/obs_6.5/java-linux-x86/bin/keytool -list -alias tomcat -keystore /data/obs/conf/keystore

### Make sure /data/obs/conf/server.xml has the correct keystore folder path, and that it uses the same password that you set earlier
<-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 --> <!-- <Connector port="8443" maxThreads="200"
scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="path to your keystore file" keystorePass="changeit" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```